# PowerPoint presentations won't open on mac but I can see their preview on Finder. It says password-protected but it is NOT password-protected

Tags: ms-office, libreoffice, open-office

Below is the powerpoint presentation I am trying to view. I can see it through Finder, as you can see below, but when I try to open it on OpenOffice or LibreOffice I get the dialog below. Again this file is not password-protected in any way, it is just one of those powerpoint presentations that people send by email.

Any ideas?

[image]

[image]

Comment: have you tried opening it in pages?

Answer (score 1):

It's shown because Preview can open PowerPoint files in view only mode; so I suppose you can open it with Preview.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I would say it is password protected to prevent modifications, the PPS is not mistaking here.

You can preview it in Quick view (hit space bar) or Preview, but that is all.

If it would be a PPT the you could view it in Power Point.

Comment: maybe @johnpristine could try changing the .pps to .ppt?

Comment: @dwightk I do not know how to do that without PowerPoint

Comment: oh, I just meant through Finder.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and discovered that for some reason the window was very small and only a corner of it was visible from the edge of the screen.

Comment: How does this address the OP's question regarding opening of a password-protected PPT?  - From Review -